# Representation theory and direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I came across the following theorem in one of the online notes regarding representation theory which I thought should have a simple proof. I am trying to prove it using basic linear algebra tools:

Theorem:
If W is a subspace of a Hermitian vector space (V, ( , )) let $W^{\perp}= \{v|<v,w>=0, \forall w\in W\}$ then $V=W\oplus W^{\perp}$ (direct sum)

(Here, V and W are finite dimensional)

I do have a rough idea as to how to go about this proof but I am not sure how to formulate it rigorously:

First just to be sure, I have to show that intersection of $W$ and  $W^{\perp} $ is trivial that is they intersect at a single point and then show $dim W^{\perp}= dim V-dim W$. Maybe we also need gram matrix to go about this but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to show this only for finite dimensional $V$? or finite dimensional $W$, to be slightly more general?  It is true for closed subspace $W$.

Comment: @hardmath: V and W are finite dimensional.

Comment: For the trivial intersection, consider $u \in W \cap W^\perp$.  What can be said about $u$?

Comment: @hardmath: We can take the inner product of u with itself and let it be 0. this would imply that u=0

Comment: The next thing you want is not that the dimensions add, what you want is $W + W^\prep = V$, i.e., every vector in $V$ can be written as a sum $w + w'$ where $w \in W$ and $w' \in W^\perp$.  Given $v \in V$, how could we pick a $w \in W$ in a way that depends on $v$?  Once $w$ is picked we'll *define* $w' = v - w$ and then have to prove that $w' \in W^\perp$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $V = W \oplus W^\perp$, we need to show that $W\cap W^\perp = \{\vec{0}\}$ and $V = W + W^\perp$.

If we want a some vector $\vec{v}$ in both $\vec{v}\in W$ and $\vec{v}\in W^\perp$, then it follows that 
$$
<\vec{v},\vec{w}> = 0, \forall w\in W~~~~~\text{and in particular, since $\vec{v}\in W$}~~~~~<\vec{v},\vec{v}> = 0
$$
It is a basic property of any inner product that this only occurs if $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$. Thus  $W\cap W^\perp = \{\vec{0}\}$.

Next, suppose $\beta = \{\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2,..\vec{u}_m\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $W$. This basis can be extended to $\gamma = \beta\cup\{\vec{u}_{m+1},..\vec{u}_n\}$ an orthonormal basis for $V$. We claim that $\delta = \{\vec{u}_{m+1},..\vec{u}_n\}$ is a basis for $W^\perp$.

It is evident that the vectors in $\delta$ are linearly independent. Now, we show they span $W^\perp$. Consider any vector $\vec{v}\in W^\perp$. Since $\vec{v}\in V$ also, we can say that
$$
\vec{v} = a_1\vec{u}_1 + a_2\vec{u}_2 + \cdots + a_n\vec{u}_n
$$
Since $\vec{v}\in W^\perp$ it follows that
$$
<\vec{v},\vec{u}_i> = <a_1\vec{u}_1 + a_2\vec{u}_2 + \cdots + a_n\vec{u}_n,\vec{u}_i> = a_i<\vec{u}_i,\vec{u}_i> = a_i = 0~~~~1 \leq i \leq m
$$
Thus $\vec{v} = a_{m+1}\vec{u}_{m+1} + \cdots + a_n\vec{u}_n$ so $W^\perp \subseteq span(\delta)$. Observe that $\vec{u}_i\in W^\perp$ if $m<i\leq n$, since $\beta$ is orthonormal
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
<\vec{u}_i,\vec{w}> &=& <\vec{u}_i,a_1\vec{u}_1 + a_2\vec{u}_2 + \cdots + a_m\vec{u}_m>\\ &=& a_1<\vec{u}_i,\vec{u}_1> + \cdots + a_m<\vec{u}_i,\vec{u}_m> \\&=& 0 +\cdots + 0 \\&=& 0\end{eqnarray}
$$
Thus the inner product of any linear combination of $\vec{u}_m...\vec{u}_n$ with some vector $\vec{w}\in W$ will also be zero, so $span(\delta) \subseteq W^\perp$. It follows that $span(\delta) = W^\perp$, and $\delta$ is a basis for $W^\perp$.

It is evident that $V = W + W^\perp$, since the union of the bases for $W$ and $W^\perp$ is a basis for $V$: $\beta = \gamma \cup \delta$.

We have satisfied $W\cap W^\perp = \{\vec{0}\}$ and $V = W + W^\perp$, so $V = W \oplus W^\perp$.

NOTE: I realize this proof is far from neat and inelegantly unconcise. I am open to suggestions.